# Missing Node Editor Header Bar at Bottom

Tags: node-editor, interface

I'm looking at the node editor and somehow ended up losing the header bar at the bottom of the node window (e.g., it had the "add" menu to add nodes). This was done when I dragged part of the window to try to resize it, but instead it was the menu bar and it reduced it to size zero instead of moving the window I was interested in.

Many suggestions say you can split the window and simply select the info or other bar you want...but the menu to do this has itself disappeared and a split window is a duplicate of the original with the missing bar:

[image]

How do I get the "add" and other node menus back if splitting the window never provides the menu to select what is viewed? Any new window has the same empty bottom bar as the bad window and no means to tell it to select anything different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If header somehow disappeared and there isn't way to use "+" button to get it back, try using *Toggle Header* command from <kbd>Space</kbd> menu. In the current editor window it will hide the header if it's present and open it if it's hidden.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of how to use that...this would indeed be the preferred way to deal with it. It is odd to have the "+" disappear, but I'm still a bit new to this and have not used the space bar for controlling things before...this will now be my first thing to look at if an interface does something I don't understand :)

Comment: @D.Stimits I'd say that the missing plus is a bug (maybe minor one) since it should be present regardless which side did you start splitting windows from. This solution is more a workaround using another techinque and I'm glad it worked. Space menu indeed sometimes provides useful information about e.g. shortcuts for commands

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I split the window to create a copy from one direction I never get the little "+" tab to pull the bar out...I have to split the window from a different direction. Seems like a bug that if split it one way the menu can be pulled out, but that the "+" does work when opened from a different direction (Blender 2.79 on Linux). Anyway, if someone runs into this, split your window from a different direction if the one you are using won't allow adding the bar back in.